# How to set user profile

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

I want the user to create a profile for himself, but I do not know exactly what to do.
When I do this code, the profiles of all the users change and become one
this is controller for user panel

```
public function UpdateUser(Request $request, User $user)
{
    if (!is_null($request->user_image && $request->job)) {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'user_image' => ['required', 'mimes:jpg,png,jpeg', 'max:5120'],
            'job'        => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:14'],
        ]);
        $file = $request->file('user_image');
        $file_path = '/images/' . 'user' . '/';
        $file->move(public_path($file_path), $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $data['user_image'] = $file_path . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    }
    User::query()->update($data);

    return redirect('/user-profile');
}
```

this is code for blade:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('user.update')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @method('PATCH')
    @csrf
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">آپلود عکس</span>
        </div>
        <input type="file" name="user_image" class="form-control" placeholder="user_image" aria-label="user_image"
               aria-describedby="basic-addon1" value="{{old('user_image')}}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">تخصص</label>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="job" id="job" placeholder=" تخصص خود را وارد کنید"
               value="{{old('job')}}">
    </div>

    <div class=" d-flex">
        <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-success mr-auto">
            <div>ثبت</div>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have your validation inside the if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User::query()->update(...)` is going to update every row in the table since you're not constraining it in any way.

Since this page is for the currently authenticated user, use the `user()` method from the `$request`. You could use the `Auth` facade or the `auth()` helper function instead.

```
$request->user()->update($data);
```

---

This isn't your only issue though. `!is_null($request->user_image && $request->job)` will always be `true` since `$request->user_image && $request->job` will always produce a `boolean` value which will never be considered `null` so you might as well just remove the `if` statement.

Also, (not that it really matters in this case since the `if` statement would always run) if you have a variable defined in a `if` statement, you should also define a default value i.e. for when the condition is `false`.

```
public function UpdateUser(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'user_image' => ['required', 'mimes:jpg,png,jpeg', 'max:5120'],
        'job'        => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:14'],
    ]);

    $file = $request->file('user_image');

    $file_path = '/images/' . 'user' . '/';
    $file->move(public_path($file_path), $file->getClientOriginalName());
    $data['user_image'] = $file_path . $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $request->user()->update($data);

    return redirect('/user-profile');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this line your query on all users not specific user

```
User::query()->update($data);
```

try this

```
$user->update($data);
```